# extraction of entire row based on single column cell

Tags: excel

How can I extract entire data of a row based on single column value ? for example. I have a criteria that matches one of a column value lets say 67 which is in row 31 column F31,  how can extract all the details of the row 31 with all column values

Comment: Pivot table filtered by `67` would work

Answer (score 0):

You may use [index-match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/) .

Say for example, A31:E31(Sheet1) is your required value.. with F31( as your reference/matching value. And based on the value you specified in A1, you want to load A31:E31 values in A2:E2 . You may put in A2(Sheet2) `=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet1!$F:$F,0),COLUMN())`  and drag it to the right..

Have a read + try.. If it doesn't work as you intended.. you may share a sample data to clarify the case. (:

Hope it helps..